# ¿Es posible registrar cuántas veces se ha pulsado un elemento en un listview?

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

estoy cacharreando con Android Studio y me gustaría hacer un contador en función de las veces que se ha pulsado elemento dentro de un listview. Estoy buscando por mil sitios y no encuentro nada, a ver si me podéis echar un cable.

Muchas gracias, un saludo.

Comment: Agrega lo que has intentado o realizado por favor, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Pues si los elementos de la lista son constantes, utilizando el evento OnItemClickListener puedes obtener la posición del elemento clicleado, apartir de ahí ya queda de tu parte como almacenar esta información, en una base de datos como preferencias de usuario o hasta en un archivo plano

Aqui un ejemplo

```
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
    Toast.makeText(SuggestionActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
```

Position te trae el valor del indice clicado